# Paypal Express Checkout PHP, load it into a fancybox rather than a popup

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am using PayPal Express checkout, specifically for digital goods and the way it works is that when you click the pay now button it will popup with a new window which loads paypal and then redirects users to a success page within that popup.

The problem with that is the site I am working on is a HTML5 canvas app, so I need to trigger a javascript function on the the original page based on success or failure.

However, I do not know if it is possible through a different window, so my first thought is to load paypal inside a fancy box, which would then allow me to use something like `top.foo();`

Has anyone done this before, or can advise me on whether it is logical to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [PayPal Express Checkout for Digital Goods](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG)?  It gives you different options for how to handle the PayPal redirect stuff, and it includes the option to have it all done in a lightbox.

Comment: Thank you! I must have overlooked that